# Isolated DC-DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, opto-isolator, isolation, ground-loop, digital-isolator

We have a design in which we need to isolate a communications signal coming from a TTL serial port and going to a DUT sitting on a bed of nails (functional tester).

The supply voltage ranges from 2.5 to 3.6 V and we need the isolated DC-DC converter to be able to follow any voltage in the input range. This means the output voltage should be equal to the input voltage for any voltage between 2.5 and 3.6 V.
The output current should not be less than 400 mA.

This input voltage is needed to accommodate many products under test.

I was not able to find any SMD or through-hole DC-DC converter that meets my requirements. Is there a way to make a design that meets these requirements? What kind of isolated DC-DC converter is best suited for this application?

In the picture below is a high-level description of what we need.

[image]

Comment: Hi Renaud. part recommendations will be closed. can you reformulate your question to not be a part recommendation?

Comment: Welcome! Following the input voltage would make it very rare for a COTS. Why is this needed? If you need it, you probably need to design it yourself.

Comment: Hi Winny, I updated my question with the answer. In fact the circuit needs to accomodate various products with various supply voltages, that's the reason.

Comment: My best suggestion is to try to find a different solution to solve that rather than to follow input voltage. How often will it be changed? Can you use something simple as a switch to set it? If not, it is possible to design such a converter. You can solve it with clever design of the regulation loop with just about any topology. In deep CCM, any forward-derived topology should automatically follow input voltage.

Comment: Something like these one https://recom-power.com/en/products/dc-dc-converters/dc-dc-converters-regulated/rec-c-dc-dc-regulated.html?1

Comment: It does not say anywhere that it will follow input nor operate down to 2.5 V, but worth a try: https://g.recomcdn.com/media/Datasheet/pdf/.fMCyPUAX/.tc19e3c8e94f6e89a17af/Datasheet-71/R1SX.pdf

Comment: The cheap "chopper" type converters, without regulation, are simply an oscillator, transformer and rectifier, so follow the input voltage more or less.  The diode drop being the tricky part. The current requirement is exceptional though. Do you really need so much? How about an isolated supply with digital control, instead of the external supply plus isolator?

Comment: This kind of power supply need a separated "channel" for feedback. Idea is used in some power supplies. Wiil try to think about.

Comment: This kind of supply exist, XP Power, but for very high voltages ... some kV.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11036#/

Comment: Are you sure it needs to follow the input voltage, or would it be possible to arrange it so that there's a fixed input voltage, but the converter itself can be adjusted using an additional channel of your test equipment? That feels like it would be easier, to me.

Comment: I would just use a programmable power supply in this application. Any decent programmable power supply will have an isolated USB or Ethernet interface.

Comment: If the power supply is already isolated, why do you need a separate isolating DC/DC converter? There is nothing else connected to the power supply.

Comment: What kind of isolation do you need, and why?

Comment: You may analyse the SN6505 TI Transformer Driver IC for simple dc/dc isolated converter circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Probabily, you won't find such a module or component.

Isn't a better/cheaper option to isolate a main higher voltage and generate the voltage rails you need or control a second variable voltage rail?

Look, you could use 5V input 5V output isolated DC DC converter and on the isolated side you could:

- Generate the voltages rails you need and select them by a switch
- Send an isolated analog or digital signal that controls a variable
  voltage regulator on the isolated side.

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide a square wave and a simple full bridge to the primary of a small 1:1 transformer, rectify and filter the output, and "Bob's your uncle". I have done this using a common mode choke, at about 50 kHz. The square wave greatly reduces the need for filtering. But the output will always be a little lower than the input, although using Schottky diodes or perhaps active rectification will get you close. If you wind your own transformer you can add a few extra turns on the output to compensate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKu2Cu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That should work, but for some reason the simulator seems to treat the transformer primary as a short circuit. I know this implementation has crossover spikes, but the transformer should not be drawing 20 amps. I'll reproduce this in LTspice where I'm on more familiar ground.

I found that the upper and lower MOSFETs of the bridge did not conduct equally, causing net DC through the transformer primary. I made a better inverting driver and added a capacitor to eliminate the problem. And I used a center tapped transformer with two Schottky diodes and a 30 ohm (100 mA) load.

[image: 3V DC-DC converter]